# Comparing two pairs of columns between two tables and returning the column from a third table

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have three tables:

Table1

`table1` can have anywhere from 50K to 800k unique rows.  By this, I mean that the combination of all the values in each row are unique, although sometimes, some columns will match up. It’s POSSIBLE that an entire row will match except the `NAME` column, but it’s very, very unlikely. The NAME column will always be unique.

The `NAME` column is type `varchar(20)`. The remainder of the columns for each record are all type `varchar(6)`, where every two columns is a set pair and the table has up to 21 set pairs (ie 43 columns total). Here is an example `table1` showing one set pair for 4 records (I used single characters here for ease but don’t forget they are type `varchar(6)`):

`table1`

```
NAME        pair1_1     pair1_2     ...up to pair21_1 - pair21_2
00001A      A           B       
00002A      A           A       
00003A      B           C       
00004A      A           B       
…up to 800k rows
```

Table2

`table2` is set up exactly the same way except it contains completely different records of the same exact type (here there can be anywhere from 1 to 200 rows)

`table2`

```
NAME        pair1_1    pair1_2    ...up to pair21_1 - pair21_2
1234B       A          B
5678B       A          A
9101B       C          C
1213B       A          B        
…up to 200 rows
```

Table3

`table3` is associated with a single row in `table2` and can be characterized as every possible result of a comparison between that single row in `table2` to any possible row that COULD BE in `table1`. It’s probably best to call it by the `NAME` in `table2` pertaining to it (let’s use just the first and call it `table1234B` because if there are 200 rows in table2, there are 200 different associated `table3`s).

This 3rd table will contain 4 rows. It has a `NAME` column which is a `varchar(20)` and 21 sets of 7 columns (each associated with a different pair from `table1` and `table2`). The additional columns `res1_1`, `res1_2…res21_7` are type `decimal(30,7)`.

Here’s what it looks like:

`table1234B`

```
NAME        res1_1  res1_2  res1_3  res1_4  res1_5  res1_6  res1_7  ….res21_7
1234B       12.30   1.000   0.2500  1.000   2.000   2.10    25.00   ….
```

I want to use the combination of shared data in the pairs of columns from `table1` and `table2` (ie how they match up) as the condition to select data from `table1234B` (I will show some of this below). Only coinciding pairs will be compared. `pair1_1` and `pair1_2` from `table1` will be compared to `pair1_1` and `pair1_2` from `table2`, the `pair2`s will only be compared with `pair2`s, `pair3`s only with `pair3`s etc. So, no cross pair comparisons are made (eg `pair1` will never be compared with `pair2`)

In this example below, the fields in `pair1_1` from each table match (A), and the fields in `pair1_2` from each table match (B) but the fields don’t match between the columns of each table.

```
NAME        Pair1_1     Pair1_2
00001A      A           B       (from table1)
1234B       A           B       (from table2)
```

So I want to SELECT say `pair1_4` from `table1234B` and associate it with the comparison between records 00001A and 1234B.

If the tables were like this we can see that all 4 of the fields match.

```
NAME        pair1_1     pair1_2
00001A      A           A       (from table1)
1234B       A           A       (from table2)
```

In this instance maybe I would want to choose `pair1_1` from `table1234B`

Here we can see that `pair1_1` in `table1` matches both fields from `table2` but `pair1_2` from `table1` does not match anything.

```
NAME        pair1_1     pair1_2
00001A      A           B       (from table1)
1234B       A           A       (from table2)
```

So I want to choose say `pair1_4` from `table1234B`

The above are only 3 of the 14 possible ways the data in the column pairs can be shared between the tables (there are multiple ways they share no data between tables also) but only 7 possible columns for each pair to select from `table1234B`.

I want to select ALL of the values from `table1234B` that meet the criteria set forth from all of the possible sharing between the columns in each set of 2 from `table1` and `table2`. It will look like something like this when complete:

`1234BResult`

```
NAME        RESULTPair1     …up to Resultpair21
00001A      12.30       (res1_1 from table3)        
00002B      1.000       (res1_2 from table3)                
00003C      25.00       (res1_7 from table3)        
00004A      1.000       (res1_4 from table3)
…up to 800K rows
```

Here is my edited query I’m starting with.

```
SELECT t1.NAME as NAME, t3.pair1_4 as RESULTPair1
FROM table1 t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 t2
ON (t1.pair1_1 = t2.pair1_1 AND t1.pair1_1 <> t1.pair1_2 AND t1.pair1_2 = t2.pair1_2 AND t2.pair1_1 <> t2.pair1_2)
LEFT OUTER JOIN table1234B t3
ON t2.NAME = t3.NAME
```

…and the result of that query

```
NAME        RESULTPair1 
00001A      1.000       (res1_4 from table3)
00002B      NULL
00003A      NULL
00004A      1.000       (res1_4 from table3)
```

This is closer to what I am looking for as it leaves the `NAME`s from `table2` with different sharing open to other values from `table1234B`. I intend the remaining logic once incorporated would return the other appropriate results.

The trouble is that this only gives me the result of any situation that is AB, AB. I need to expand this to 21 pairs and potentially 200 `table3`s, including all of the different possible results from `table3` if applicable.  I can handle all the sharing logic (ie `pair1_1 = pairt2_2` or `pair1_1 <> pair2_2`) it’s expanding it to the remaining situations and potentially more records from `table2` that I am at a loss on. I need to get results for all 800k records in `table1` for all 21 pairs.

If you’ve stayed with me this long and understand all that chicken scratch, my questions are:

1. How would I edit my above query to work with a `JOIN` instead of a `WHERE`?
2. Would there be a way to expand this to efficiently include the logic of the additional possible scenarios of sharing between the fields in `table1` and `table2` so that I can see or store in a new table all 50-800k results from the `table1` to single row in `table2` comparison?
3. How the heck do I expand it to the additional 20 pairs?

**EDIT**
After being asked about the connection with table3 I realized that the column needed an edit for this to work properly. Im still having trouble figuring out how to make the query work right.  I have edited the query too. Im still having a little trouble expanding it to multiple columns. It was suggested to use INTERSECT + EXCEPT or NOT EXISTS.  I couldn't get INTERSECT to return anything whereas the query with the edit to include the left joins does.

Comment: By using a comma you are in fact joining your tables. The first comma between table `t1` and `t3` being a `cross join`, and the second comma an `inner join` (because of the where clause). Looking into  the `INTERSECT` + `EXCEPT` operators or `not exists` is probably going to be better performing, might be me, but table3, (that represents a huge amount of tables?) connection to all of this is still a tad unclear to me.

Comment: @RandiVertongen yes. There can be a large amount of table3s depending on how many rows I want to have in table 2.

Comment: The third table is the result set of calculations based on frequencies of the shared field values from tables 1 and 2. Having the entire population of 142 possible values to choose from will be much more efficient than doing 16,800,000 calculations for each row in table2 on the fly....I hope that’s a better explanation

Comment: I figured this out today actually and will answer it in a bit if anyone is interested. I’ve been trying to figure out a way to index this type of comparison for a long time and finally have something that works and in an incredibly efficient manner for 1 row in table 2 (ie millions of calculations). Is it the most efficient? I don’t know yet. Maybe you guys can mess with it. One of the things I want to do is index all the varchar(6) data into integer values with an etl to an additional table to make the comparison faster. Two columns 1-A, 2-B, 3-C etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got a working query. It joins 21 derived tables (one for each of the 21 pairs compared). They are joined with 20 `FULL OUTER JOIN`s rather than `LEFT JOIN`s, each with sets of 14 subqueries combined with `UNION ALL`s so I'll just give a general form with some comments. It does 67,000 comparisons in 5 seconds flat.

```
SELECT COALESCE (t4.NAME, t5.NAME,...t25.NAME) AS NAME,
                t4.RESULTPair1, t5.RESULTPair2,...t25.RESULTPair21           

FROM ((SELECT t1.NAME AS NAME, t3.RESULTPair1_1 AS RESULTPair1
     FROM table1 t1
     INNER JOIN table2 t2
     ON (t1.pair1_1 = t1.pair1_2 AND    ---logic between table1 and table2 for AAAA
         t1.pair1_1 = t2.pair1_1 AND
         t1.pair1_1 = t2.pair1_2)
     INNER JOIN table1234B t3
     ON t2.NAME = t3.NAME) 

     UNION ALL

     (SELECT t1.NAME AS NAME, t3.RESULTPair1_2 AS RESULTPair1
     FROM table1 t1
     INNER JOIN table2 t2
     ON (---LOGIC FOR AAAB---)  ---I wont bore you with the rest of the matching logic unless someone is really interested
     INNER JOIN table1234B t3
     ON t2.NAME = t3.NAME) 

     ------Repeat the above query for each set of logic AAAB, AABA, ABAA, BAAA etc. with 13
     ------total UNION ALL (each set of logics will take care of every possible situation of
     ------sharing between the tables and each t1.NAME is different so UNION ALL will be more
     ------efficient, COALESCE for the NAME field returns a full column for NAME)

    UNION ALL

    (SELECT t1.NAME AS NAME, t3.RESULTPair1_7 AS RESULTPair1
    FROM OFFENDERS t1
    INNER JOIN table2 t2
    ON  (---LOGIC FOR AABB---)
    INNER JOIN table1234B t3
    ON t2.NAME = t3.NAME)) t4 --aabb

     ——-now move through the remaining result pairs up to 21 (ie derived table25)
FULL OUTER JOIN
     ——-subqueries for result set2
ON t4.NAME = t5.NAME
     ——-subqueries for resultsets 3-20
ON t23.NAME = t24.NAME
FULL OUTER JOIN

    ((SELECT t1.NAME AS NAME, t3.RESULTPair21_1 AS RESULTPair21
    FROM table1 t1
    INNER JOIN table2 t2
    ON  (---LOGIC FOR AAAA---)
    INNER JOIN table1234B t3
    ON t2.NAME = t3.NAME)  ---aaaa

    UNION ALL

    -------remaining sets of logic for RESULTPair21

    SELECT t1.NAME AS NAME, t3.RESULTPair21_7 AS RESULTPair21
    FROM table1 t1
    INNER JOIN table2 t2
    ON  (---LOGIC FOR AABB---)
    INNER JOIN table3 t3
    ON t2.NAME = t3.NAME)) t25 --aabb

ON t24.NAME = t25.NAME
```

It's a work in progress so if there's something I can do to improve it, let me know! Like I said in the above comments, I think I'm going to set up another table to index the varchar(6) fields to integers then use the integers for comparison. So now table1 and table2 will look like this:

```
table1
NAME        pair1_1     pair1_2     ...up to pair21_1 - pair21_2
00001A      1           2       
00002A      1           1       
00003A      2           3       
00004A      1           2       
…up to 800k rows 

table2
NAME        pair1_1    pair1_2    ...up to pair21_1 - pair21_2
1234B       1          2
5678B       1          1
9101B       3          3
1213B       1          2        
…up to 200 rows
```

...and the additional index to make comparison faster and in case I ever want to retrieve the actual sets of data:

```
intIndex
pairs    code
A        1
B        2
C        3
D        4
...
up to all possible varchar(6) character strings
```

I have added the index table and now have comparisons of integers instead of the varchar(6) columns. 67,000 table1 row query produces 21 columns in 5 seconds for the varchar(6) columns vs 4 seconds for the integer columns. 1.4 million calculations. Anyone got any other suggestions that might help me out?